# I cannot find my test payments in sandbox

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

[SOLVED - Sandbox bug?]
I'm trying to setup a paypal payment with IPN.
The IPN works well and gives me the right answer but:
-I cannot find the test transactions in my sandbox business account page list (only in the sandbox user account of the payer as pending) 
-The transaction ID shown in receipt page when I pay is different from the one stored by the IPN script (for example  2P3936636X9979307 in receipt page and 36E923443V406174V in the IPN for the same transaction)
Where is the mistake?
Thanks

Tommaso

Comment: I think we might need to see some code for the scripts to spot the mistake?

Comment: This morning I try the same code in paypal website instead of sandbox paypal and everything worked perfectly. So I'm quite sure that is only a sandbox matter. Thanks for your help